# Creating a data driven resource manager while keeping the VS2010 designer features

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resx

I'm quite used to consume resx designer generated classes, for a clean coding and to avoid mistakes.

However, in a specific project, I need to rely to a database table, containing all labels and their translations in several languages.

I could simply create my own class and get the translated label, however I'd also like to take advantage of VS2010 resource manager and autogenerated *.Designer.cs classes.

I didn't figure out how to do that.
The *.Designer.cs file contains the following comment:

```
// This class was auto-generated by the StronglyTypedResourceBuilder
// class via a tool like ResGen or Visual Studio.
// To add or remove a member, edit your .ResX file then rerun ResGen
// with the /str option, or rebuild your VS project.
```

So, I suppose I must use the StronglyTypedResourceBuilder (or my own version of this class).

But how to automatically build the class during the design?
And how to save/retrieve data from the DB?